# Which attributes does Active Directory currently use for POSIX compatibility?

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap

In a heterogeneous environment that uses Windows Active Directory as the central directory, some attributes are essential for compatibility with Linux systems.

- uidNumber
- gidNumber
- gecos
- loginShell
- homeDirectory

Should I be using these exact attribute names? Why do I keep seeing references to *Microsoft Services For Unix (MSSFU)* and attributes like `MSSFU2x-uidNumber`? Can I ignore those entirely?

For bonus points, please provide some background into the history of those MSSFU attributes. Which attributes are deprecated, and how long have they been that way? Why were there so many versions of *Microsoft Services for Unix*, and why did they ever use so many different names?

Comment: You should be using unixHomeDirectory instead of homeDirectory

Answer (score 0):

"uid" (effectively the account name) is often used for dual protocol access to NFS (Windows/Linux). uid is unusual in that it is a multivalue attribute.

In addition, for file system compatibility, it is necessary to add an Active directory group with the same gidNumber as is assigned to a given user account. Each of these groups should have "posixGroup" added to the objectClass property.

Each Active Directory user account should have "posixAccount" and "user" added as values to the objectClass property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/create-volumes-dual-protocol#manage-ldap-posix-attributes

Regarding the MS-SFU, these are user for Kerberos constrained delegation (basically impersonation).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/MS-SFU/3bff5864-8135-400e-bdd9-33b552051d94

Kerberos constrained delegation is turned off by default. It can be handy for certain scenarios, for example you need and admin account to remotely alter the saved passwords for a service account on 50 servers. You can enable kerberos constrained delegation on an admin account, basically allowing it to impersonate the service account and store passwords as the service account.

For what you are asking, these attributes can probably be ignored, I don't believe there is any synchronization with other directories that would be needed for compatibility or anything like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).